# same redirect rule on 2 domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm running 2 domains on the same virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName www.example.de
    ServerAlias www.example.de example.de example.co.uk www.example.co.uk
    DocumentRoot C:/inetpub/wwwroot/example_ml
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

and trying to apply the same redirect rule in my htaccess for both of the domains

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ http://www.example.de/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.*)$ http://www.example.de/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/(.*)$ http://www.example.de/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but doesn't seem to work
on each `example.co.uk/tag_name` I'm getting redirected to `example.de/tag_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define the rules two times, try this :

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```